# How to add button layout constraints ARSKView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, ios11, arkit

I'm using SpriteKit (ARSKView) with UIKit elements, and I'd like to add a button that stays in the bottom left of the screen at all times.  When pressed, the button would clear all nodes.

This is the code I tried to get the button to display, but when I try adding the bottom anchor and left anchor constraints, I get this error

> Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and  because they have no common ancestor. 
>   Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view
>   hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

The button works fine when tapped, but **how can I add layout constraints in ARSKView?**

And **how do I get the button to clear all the nodes from the scene?**

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and node count
    sceneView.showsFPS = true
    sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
 //   sceneView.showsPhysics = true

    // Load the SKScene from 'Scene.sks'
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
        sceneView.presentScene(scene)



    }


    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue:0, alpha: 0.4)
    button.setTitle("Clear Screen", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.view.addSubview(button)


}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")

}
```

Comment: Your tags are wrong,  you are using UIKit here, you need help in that area, not sprite kit

Comment: Do you know what it's supposed to be?  I'm new to SpriteKit

Comment: I edited your question,  your problem is you need to add the button to the view first, and you do not want to anchor it (sceneView is your parent)  Look at your storyboard file, you can create your button and constraints visually, instead of having to type all of the code out.

Comment: When I try to drag a button onto the view it completely replaces ARSKView leaving me with a blank screen plus my button.  In fact, anything I try to drag onto the screen replaces the ARSKView, even a regular UIView.  That's why I was trying to create the button programmatically.

Comment: do a blank UIView first, then add the ARSKView, followed by the button to the UIView

Comment: Who ever at apple designed the UI for storyboarding made it a real pain,  all views can have subviews, no idea who thought it would be a great idea to restrict it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thank you, adding a view then the ARSKView under it worked.  Do you know how I would be able to make the button work?  What code is necessary to make it clear all of the nodes off of the scene?

Comment: you add an IBAction to your view controller, then in the function you can access the scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I know but what code exactly?  The only thing I could find online is this ----> rootNode.enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock { (node, stop) -> Void in
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }                                                                            --------------But that isn't working.